# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript

Meu código está gerando erro e pelo que pesquisei seria erro de sintaxe mas não to conseguindo achar aqui e o Sublime Text 2 não tem corretor. Poderiam me ajudar? Segue o código:

```
var Padrao = {

    /**
    * Init
    */
    init : function(){

        //Exibe Tela de Login/Minha Conta
        $('.login').click(Padrao.abreLogin);

        //Exibe Carrinho de Compras
        $('.carrinho-botao').click(Padrao.exibeCarrinho);

        //Chama o carrousel de Banner
        Padrao.carrouselBanner();
    },

    //Exibe Tela de Login/Minha Conta
    abreLogin : function(){
        $('.minha-conta').toggle(200);
    },

    //Exibe Carrinho de Compras
    exibeCarrinho : function(){
        $('.carrinho-aberto').toggle(200);
    },

    //Carrousel de banner
    carrouselBanner : function(){

        //recupera a qtd de elementos da lista
        var elementos = $('.destaque-banner ul li').length;

        //atribui automatico o valor de width para a ul
        $('.destaque-banner ul').css({width : 990 * elementos});


        //define e imprime a quantidade de bullets de acordo com o numero de elementos
        for(var i = 0; i < elementos; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                $('.bullets-area ul').append('<li><a href="javascript:void" index="' + parseInt(i) + '" class="sel"> x </a></li>');
            } else {
                $('.bullets-area ul').append('<li><a href="javascript:void" index="' + parseInt(i) + '"> x </a></li>');
            }
        }

        $('.bullets-area ul li a').click(function(){
            var desloca = $(this).attr('index');
            //alert(desloca);
            $('.destaque-banner ul').animate({'margin-left': desloca * -1000});
        });
    }
};

$(Padrao.init);
```

Comment: O erro é só `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`? Não tem mais nenhum detalhe que poderia ajudar a identificar o erro?

Comment: Não tem nada de errado com seu código, testei em um compilador e não acusa erros. Onde você o está declarando/chamando na sua página?

Comment: Amigo Paulo Roberto. O erro que o navegador acusava era ali onde eu defino href="javascript:void". Tinha faltado o (0). Falha minha mas já descobri. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Poste-o como resposta @user5101 :}

Comment: Como PauloRoberto falou, poste como resposta e selecione a sua própria resposta

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar o [javacriptlint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) para isso.

Só copia e cola o código lá e ele te mostra erros de sintaxe.

O site é uma ferramenta [lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29). Infelizmente não tem uma página na wiki para ferramentas lint em português ainda, mas são ferramentas que analisam o código procurando erros de sintaxe e algumas más práticas. A grande maioria das linguagems de programação tem ferramentas desse tipo.

Comment: Tentei e mesmo assim não apresenta nada. Apenas uns warnings que corrigi mas aparentemente nada fora do normal.

Comment: @user5101 O erro possívelmente está em algum código que foi declarado anteriormente, então.

Comment: Estou usando apenas a biblioteca jquery, esse arquivo que postei (padrao.js) e a biblioteca less.js!

Comment: O link está quebrado!

Comment: @Heitor podes usar qualquer outro site que faça lint, por exemplo, [jslint](https://www.jslint.com/)

Comment: @fotanus obrigado, descobri qual era meu problema, era questão de encoding de caracteres, meu json estava correto de acordo com vários sites que usei, mas em tempo de execução dava esse erro de input...

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, tenta colocar uma virgula no final por exemplo:

```
 $('.bullets-area ul li a').click(function(){
            var desloca = $(this).attr('index');
            //alert(desloca);
            $('.destaque-banner ul').animate({'margin-left': desloca * -1000});
        });
    },
};

$(Padrao.init);
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tem nada de errado com o código em si. O problema está oculto nos links com Javascript que são adicionados pelo código.

Ao invés de:

```html
<a href="javascript:void">x</a>
```

Faça:

```html
<a href="javascript:;">x</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Aqui está seu código corrigido

```
var Padrao = {

    /**
    * Init
    */
    init : function(){

        //Exibe Tela de Login/Minha Conta
        $('.login').click(Padrao.abreLogin);

        //Exibe Carrinho de Compras
        $('.carrinho-botao').click(Padrao.exibeCarrinho);

        //Chama o carrousel de Banner
        Padrao.carrouselBanner();
    },

    //Exibe Tela de Login/Minha Conta
    abreLogin : function(){
        $('.minha-conta').toggle(200);
    },

    //Exibe Carrinho de Compras
    exibeCarrinho : function(){
        $('.carrinho-aberto').toggle(200);
    },

    //Carrousel de banner
    carrouselBanner : function(){

        //recupera a qtd de elementos da lista
        var elementos = $('.destaque-banner ul li').length;

        //atribui automatico o valor de width para a ul
        $('.destaque-banner ul').css({width : 990 * elementos});


        //define e imprime a quantidade de bullets de acordo com o numero de elementos
        for(var i = 0; i < elementos; i++){
            index = parseInt(i,10); // faltou um parametro aqui, parseInt(string, radix), você não tinha passado o radix
            if(i === 0){ // como era uma comparação de tipos o lint pede que seja feita uma comparação usando "==="
                $('.bullets-area ul').append('<li><a href="javascript:void" index="' + index  + '" class="sel"> x </a></li>');
            } else {
                $('.bullets-area ul').append('<li><a href="javascript:void" index="' + index  + '"> x </a></li>');
            }
        }

        $('.bullets-area ul li a').click(function(){
            var desloca = $(this).attr('index');
            //alert(desloca);
            $('.destaque-banner ul').animate({'margin-left': desloca * -1000});
        });
    }
};

$(Padrao.init);
```

Na linha 40 [jslint](/questions/tagged/jslint) estava reclamando da falta do segundo parâmetro no `parseInt()` por recomendação ele deve receber 2 parâmetros onde o segundo é opcional `parseInt(string, radix)`

> Parameter - (string)  Required. The string to be parsed
>
> Description - (radix) Optional. A number (from 2 to 36) that represents the numeral system to be used

Na linha 41 o [jslint](/questions/tagged/jslint) estava reclamando do tipo de comparação então a comparação foi trocada de `==` para `===`

Comment: Faltou dizer o que estava errado. :)

Comment: O parseInt() funciona sim com um parâmetro, mas como o @ErlonCharles colocou nos comentários, o JSLint não "aconselha" o uso dessa forma, pois se passar "0x16" (hexadecimal) como parâmetro ele vai virar o inteiro 22 e não 0 ou 16 como é de se esperar.