# Como remover "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Estou rodando um script no console do Google e recebo o erro "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input". Não encontrei o erro de sintaxe desse código, pesquisei em perguntas anteriores, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5527/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280196/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-help), mas não achei algo que pudesse me indicar onde está o erro desse código. Segue o código que estou tentando rodar no console:

```
 <script>
        var cidades = ["São Paulo", "Criciuma", "Curitiba", "Itajai", "Rio do Sul", "Erichim"];
        for (var i = 0; i < cidades.legth; i++){
            var str = cidades[i];
            if(str.lenght == 8){
                document.write(str);
                document.write("|");
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Alguém saberia dizer como posso eliminar esse erro para rodar esse exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem erros de sintaxe: O correto é: `length`, isto é, o comprimento do array `cidades` e o comprimento de cada item desse mesmo array.

```js
var cidades = ["São Paulo", "Criciuma", "Curitiba", "Itajai", "Rio do Sul", "Erichim"];
        for (var i = 0; i < cidades.length; i++){
            var str = cidades[i];
            console.log(str);
            if(str.length == 8){
                document.write(str);
                document.write("|");
            }
        }
```

**Demo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Arrumei esse erro e rodei, mas ele me retorna "undefined" ao invés de retornar os nomes das cidades. Não deveria retornar os nomes dessa vez?

Comment: Ele retorna undefined porque, na verdade, não é uma função, no entanto, mostra na tela do seu browser as cidades Criciuma e Curitiba